# Refresh bug with UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a UICollectionView that uses a UICollectionViewFlowLayout in conjunction with a UIRefreshControl. When I pull to refresh, the following block of code is called

```
self.content = nil;
self.content = [[[posts reverseObjectEnumerator] allObjects] copy];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
    [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
 });
```

What ends up happening is when the collectionview is pulled down to refresh, only cells at index 0 and 1 are visible. However, when the control is released, the cell at index 2 pops back into view and `(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)` gets called to dequeue the cell at index 2. This happens BEFORE `reloadData` is called. So the order of execution is such

1. Pull down control
2. Cell at index 2 goes off screen
3. Release
4. Cell at index 2 comes back on screen
5. (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) is called on that cell
6. `[self.collectionView reloadData];` is called
7. The cells at indexes 0, 1, and 2 all are dequeued in (UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)

It's pretty subtle but there's a slight flicker as, for some godforsaken reason, the cell at index 0 gets set to the cell at index 2's content and then set back to the correct content. There's another problem though because my UICollectionViewSubclass has both a `UITextView` and `UIImageView` so even though the textview just flickers, the images at 0 and 2 get swapped and don't switch until I refresh again.

Anyone have any ideas how to stop 2 from getting reloaded before the called to reloadData happens? or any fix really

EDIT: I discovered that this doesn't necessarily happen once you release the refresh control, it's actually when the refresh control is pulled far enough to trigger the refresh and then it does a weird little jump/flicker on the screen. In this case, the lone cell got dequeued and then it resets correctly. This is only if I don't release the control

Comment: Do you have this image switching problem if you scroll so the cell at index 2 goes off screen?

Comment: Instead of using `reloadData` have you thought of reloading the cells on screen with [reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionView/reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:)

Comment: @rdelmar no it doesn't, only when the refresh control snaps back into place. squarefrog, yeah I tried just reloading the visible cells but the cell at index 2 is getting dequeued before the data finishes loading and before reloadData is called